# Mule loop of flow references run in very odd order

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I have a loop that runs three flow references in order. At least that is the plan. Run in the debugger, processing takes place in the following unexpected order:

- the first flow-ref (A)
- the second flow-ref (B)
- the first component of flow A
- the third flow-ref (C)
- the first component of flow B
- the second component of the flow A
- the first component of flow C
- the second component of flow B
- the third component of flow A
  ...now things blow up (in 1st of flow C), since payload is not expected

I changed the processing strategy from implicit to 'synchronous' with no noticeable change.

What is going on?

```
    <flow name="Loop_until_successfull" doc:name="Loop_until_successfull" processingStrategy="synchronous">
        <flow-ref name="A" doc:name="Go to A"></flow-ref>
        <flow-ref name="B" doc:name="Go to B"></flow-ref>
        <flow-ref name="C" doc:name="Go to C"></flow-ref>
    </flow>
```

Comment: You haven't specified if you are flow-refing sub-flows or flows. Seeing the behaviour you're reporting, I guess there are flows, right? Also what's the exchange-pattern of the inbound event? one-way I guess? And what's the processing strategies of the A, B and C flows?

Comment: Also: can you show the loop config?

Comment: I never got to that part (adding a loop)

Comment: yes, the refs are are to flows... and yes: inbound is not expecting a response. I never quite got to adding a loop... and I now see that I assumed it would be different: that I could loop-until-successful across the whole (all three) flow refs. A B abd C were all implicit.  I also see that you and Gary are in the same tact. And, I changed the ref'd flows to be sync: that works as expected. Adding a loop until successful around each flow-ref would prob not make any diff there, right?

Comment: Adding until successful loops around A, B, C won't solve your problem, if you are waiting for the end result any one of those flows before moving on to the next.  If A, B, C are configured async, the until successful around any one of these will attempt to assert success as soon as it finishes firing off a message to the referenced flow.  So, if you define HTTP Status 200 as success, a call out to an HTTP Endpoint on A would return successful regardless of whether the A flow completed so long as the initial call out to the endpoint was successful.

Comment: I added while-success loops around each of the flowrefs and everything broke again, pretty much the same behaviour... also I created subflows to replaced the referenced flows, and that didn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the "Loop_until_successful" flow to synchronous will only assure that calls to "Loop_until_successful" are processed synchronously, not necessarily any other flow called by it.  You need to change each of flows called by "Loop_until_successful" to be processed synchronously to ensure you get the response back from each call out before you make a call to the next flow.  If you do this, then Loop_until_successful (I'll call L.U.S for now on) calls A, waits for a response, then calls B, waits for a response, then calls C.  The way it is configured now, L.U.S. calls A and then moves immediately on to B using the payload it has rather than waiting for the response from A.

Comment: That works. I assume request-response will play into this as well. BTW, I assume you meant 'A' in the last word, not 'B'

Comment: Yes, the exchange pattern of the inbound event plays an important role into Mule's algorithm for determining if a flow-ref => flow call will be sync or async (flow-ref => sub-flow is always sync). FWW we detail this kind of issue in chapter 2 of Mule in Action, second edition as it's always surprising to face unexpected parallelism.